# Is screen replacement the only solution?

Tags: laptop, display, lenovo-laptop, dead-pixel, stuck-pixel

From the last 3 Month my laptop screen is having some pixel issues but from the last 10 days the pixels are turning bluish green. I think this is stuck pixel issue and I have used [deadpixelfix.pl](http://deadpixelfix.pl) and [jscreenfix.com](http://www.jscreenfix.com) for almost 20 hours but there is no change whatsoever. Is screen replacement the only solution left?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What actually happened to the display three months ago? Checking the connector etc. might also be an option.

Comment: @Seth nothing notable happened. At first there was a small dot on the right side of the screen and later it became the shape of fractal and for the bluish green dots it started as a black line and about 10 days ago it started spreading.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the layers of the LCD are separating, so yes a replacement is the only option.

You may have some luck with opening up the monitor casing and pressing the layers back together but it's unlikely at best, and it'll likely happen again even if it does work.